# Why does WiFi Scanning on Android take different times with different phones

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

`android.net.wifi.WifiManager` has the `startScan()` method to perform a passive scan of the WiFi channel and when the scanning is completed `onReceive()` method is called to access the WiFi channel readings.

However, as [this webpage](http://www.droidboy.cz/2015/03/looking-under-hood-of-wifi-scans.html) shows, which I have also confirmed with my own code implementation, the passive scanning of the WiFi channels take different times with different phones. Sometimes, some platforms are even around 10 times slower..

I would like to know what causes the phones to use so much time. Is it the driver? Is it some energy saving features? Or none of them and something very different is the reason?

Comment: I'm curious, are you doing something that need to scan more rapidly? It is possible that some platform might even have back off in place to prevent really rapid scan.

Comment: Yes, indeed I need to scan the channels as fast as possible in a back-to-back manner. Also I need to have the scans at pretty much a custom rate across the platforms.

Answer (score 1):

The article gives you a hint:

> Passive scans are slower to perform, because the device needs to
>   listen on every channel for **some period of time**, waiting for
>   broadcast beacons. Beacon frames are transmitted by APs periodically
>   to announce the presence of a wireless LAN. Beacon frames contain all
>   the information about its network. This approach consumes less energy,
>   since the radio doesn't use transceiver, but only the receiver. It
>   also takes more time to finish, since it has to listen on every
>   channel.

Some period of time is different for each device. If you listen for too short a time on a channel, you might miss a beacon frame. Too long and it might take a while to enumerate all the available APs when the user first scans a new location.

Furthermore, I didn't see actual details on how those results were generated. One might imagine a smart algorithm would use a longer listen time when first in a new location but switch to shorter ones after it's been there for a while.

Comment: Yes, passive scans will take more time, but why does it take different times on different platforms? Where in the system lies that, is the question. 
I think [this is the code](http://www.droidboy.cz/2015/03/wifimanager-continuous-scanning.html) he uses for the measurements.

Comment: @Onur - Two places. The wifi radio firmware and the OS level code that initiates scan. The wifi radio firmware sets a lower limit on how fast the scan will take. The OS level will depend on google and/or the manufacturer's customizations. There is no guarantee that either of those two will optimize for speed.